# python, solve, last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: python, function

I need to callculte the point where a given function has the value 0 with Newton's method.

The function is given by:

```
def F(x):
    F = np.zeros(2)  
    F = np.array([x[0] - 0.25 * (np.cos(x[0])-np.sin(x[1])),x[1] - 0.25 * (np.cos(x[0])-2*np.sin(x[1]))])    

    return F
```

The code that I wrote for the method is:

```
def Newton(F,dFinv,x0,tol,maxit):
    x = np.zeros((x0.size,maxit))
    Converged = False
    i = 0

    for i in range(maxit):
        s = np.dot(dFinv(x), F(x))
        x -= s
        if np.linalg.norm(s) < tol*np.linalg.norm(x):
            return x, True,i

    return x,Converged,maxit
```

where `dFinv` stands for the inverse Matrix and `maxit` for the maixmum of iterations. To callculte dFinv I wrote another function (we're not allowed to use `.inv()`):

```
def dFinv(x):
    dF = np.zeros((2,2))
    dF = np.array([[ 1. + 0.25*np.sin(x[0]), 0.25*np.cos(x[1])],[-0.25* np.sin(x[0]),1+0.5*np.cos(x[1])]])

    dFinv = np.linalg.solve(dF,np.eye(2))

    return dFinv
```

but when I try to run the code (with start-point `x=np.array([1.0,1.0])`) I get the error for `solve` in `dFinv(x)`:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

I looked up, what exactly the error means, but I'm not sure how that is possible... The matrix should be square regardless of the value I give to the function...

Comment: What version of numpy are you running, I cannot replicate your issue with `1.13.0`.

Comment: I was using numpy 1.12 until a moment ago.. Updated it to 1.13.0 but now the code won't run at all anymore... The error is: 
`ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.`

Comment: Alright, it took me some time to get the new version runnig, but I have still the same problem as before, with the same error message...